# Neo4j: similar queries, one works, one fails with "NotFoundException: Unknown identifier"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What my client passes to my Neo4j persistence layer is a *collection* of pairs, and I have to look up nodes with properties corresponding to those pairs. This is the query I came up with and it seems to work (as in: it returns the expected results for my test cases):

```
START root=node(0)
MATCH (root)-[:HAS_IDENTITY_PROVIDER]->(ip)<-[:IDENTITY_PROVIDER]-(claim)<-[:CLAIM]-(user)
WHERE [ip.Name, claim.IdentityProviderId] in [['facebook', 'f111'], ['facebook', 'f222'], ['facebook', 'f333'], ['twitter', 't444'], ['facebook', 'f555']]
RETURN user.Id AS Id, user.FirstName AS FirstName, user.LastName AS LastName, user.Avatar AS Avatar, count(*) AS Score
ORDER BY Score desc, FirstName, LastName;
```

Now I'm trying to write another query that follows a similar approach, but it fails with `"NotFoundException: Unknown identifier 'user'`:

```
START root=node(0)
MATCH (root)-[:HAS_USER]->(user)
WHERE [user.FirstName, user.LastName] in [['Alice', 'Apple']]
RETURN user.Id AS Id, user.FirstName AS FirstName, user.LastName AS LastName, user.Avatar AS Avatar;
```

It complains about the `user` in the `WHERE` clause.

Why does the first one work, and the second one doesn't? I can't spot a significant difference between them.

(Also, I don't know if this approach is considered some kind of hack, or if there are better/cleaner/faster ways of accomplishing this, I'm always open for suggestions.)

Thanks!

Comment: Since that's a syntactic complaint (right?) I figured I should be able to replicate it without your data. I copied the queries and ran them in the webadmin console of a 2.0.0-M6 server, but they both execute fine. Which version of Neo4j are you running and how are you executing the queries?

Comment: @jjaderberg: this is strange. Without data in my graph, the query returns with 0 rows. When I add a user node, for example `start root=node(0) create (alice { FirstName: "Alice", LastName: "Apple" }), (root)-[:HAS_USER]->(alice);` it returns the error above. I've tried it on Neo4j 2.0.0-M5 and 2.0.0-M6.

Comment: Yes, if I run your create statement first, I get the same exception. But: if I set `root.LastName` to 'apple' and query with `WHERE [user.FirstName, root.LastName] in [['Alice', 'Apple']]`, it works again. It seems the difference between your two queries that makes the second one break is that the `user` identifier is used twice in the array in the second query. Don't know why that happens though.

Comment: @jjaderberg: no, if I use `WHERE [user.FirstName] in [['Alice']]`, it also returns the exception.

Comment: the plot thickens.. adding `WITH user` before the `WHERE...` it works, http://console.neo4j.org/r/b1yyhp. I wonder if it is related to https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1114

Comment: Yes, I'm using `WITH` as a workaround now. Must be a bug but at the very least, the principle of least surprise has been violated. I'm waiting for someone from Neo4j to step in and shed some light on this. Maybe I'll file a bug report.